# How can I print the last query with CodeIgniter and Oracle?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I print the last query using CodeIgniter 3 and Oracle?

With same code, but with MySql, I write `print_r($this->db->last_query());` and a I get successfully the print of the last query...

But if I move to Oracle db, It doesn't works for me...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return the last run query:

```
SELECT SQL_TEXT
  FROM V$SQL
 WHERE FIRST_LOAD_TIME = (SELECT MAX(FIRST_LOAD_TIME) FROM V$SQL);
```

Comment: Thank you @Nitish. But If I run your query directly in "Toad for Oracle" I get "ora-00942 table or view does not exist"

Comment: @SDiver: You will not be having access to this view. Please ask your DBA to grant you select access.

Comment: Sorry, I have understand that it's a problem of my user on that schema. Thanks, I will ask the DBA. :)

Comment: Now I can execute successfuly the query in Toad, but codeIgniter "last_query" still doesn't work for me. Any ideas? Maybe OCI8 problem? Thank you